# What is this bracket sequence syntax called in JS?

Tags: javascript, brackets

I really don't know what to google to find out the name for this syntax:

`(1,2)` seems to evaluate to `2`

`(1,2,3,"cake")` seems to evaluate to `"cake"`. 
etc

This is sometimes useful in anonymous functions in `Array.reduce`, where you need to perform a sequence of operations (say an increment) and also return the element on the right.

But where can I read about it and what's it called?

Comment: I'm not an expert but... Isn't just a good old [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator): it evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

Comment: There are **lots** of duplicates for this question.